# What user data does the Google OAuth2 scope script.external_request give access to?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, scopes

I'm attempting the verification process for an Apps Script web app that uses the URL Fetch service via class `URLFetchApp`. [Per `URLFetchApp` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), this requires the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`. I can't find any Google documentation for this scope, and it doesn't appear on [this list of OAuth2 scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes). I'm having a hard time demonstrating how my app uses the data provided by the scope when I don't actually know what user data the scope provides. I mean, I don't *think* I'm using any user data... I'm just calling API executable functions from another Google Apps Script project.

What user data is this scope giving me access to? Or do I just need to explain why/how I'm using `URLFetchApp`?

Comment: Hi ! I don't think you are using any user data apart from getting the user to use your script and connect to an external service. If you head over the editor dashboard of your script, you will see further information about this scope stating : **Connect to an external service** under project OAuth scopes. Moreover, when you run your script, the permissions it is asking for are **Create a network connection to any external service (e.g., to read or write data)**. Does this solve your questions?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf that's helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you head over the **editor dashboard** of your script, you will see further information about this scope stating :

> *Connect to an external service under project OAuth scopes.*

Moreover, when you run your script for the first time, the permissions it is asking for are:

> *Create a network connection to any external service (e.g., to read or write data)*

Therefore, despite not having much more description in the documentation (just in UrlFetchApp), I don't think you are using any user data apart from getting the user to use your script and connect to an external service.

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation if you wish to use UrlFetchApp Service then external_request is the scope you'll have to add to you manifest. Like it or not.
[UrlFetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)

Comment: Yes, I got that. I'm wondering what data it's giving me access to so I can explain to Google how I'm using it. If I can't figure it out I guess I'll just say "I'm using URLFetch and you told me I needed this scope, so...?"

Comment: I think only you will know what data an external request is giving you access to.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to think about that one. I don't think my external request is giving me access to any user data. Like I said, I'm just using URLFetchApp to call functions from another Apps Script project that's deployed as an API executable. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something...